# Bashから git を利用する際の質問です。

Tags: git

Bash を使用して以下の通り `git revert` を試しに実行してみたところ、いくつかの表示が出てきました。例えば `--quit` や `--continue` などです。これらはその後のコマンドで `--quit` と入力するような使い方になりますか？

git の使い方についてご教示いただくことは可能でしょうか？よろしくお願いします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**追記:**

`git add.` と入力すると、"Did you mean this? add" と表示されます。これは何かをその後のコマンドで入力するのでしょうか？例えば add とか Yes とかです。

```
masa582:~/workspace/tmp (test2) $ git add.
git: 'add.' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
        add
masa582:~/workspace/tmp (test2) $
```

Answer (score 2):

`git`で使用するコマンドは`git <command>`の形式で実行することが多いですが、
コマンドライン（bash）からであれば

```
$ git <command> --help
$ man git-<command>
```

等で実行方法を確認することができます(英語表記)。revertについてであれば

```
$ git revert --help
$ man git-revert
```

の様になります。

web上の公式ドキュメントであれば日本語版も用意されていますので参考にして下さい。
https://git-scm.com/book/ja/v2

Answer (score 1):

そのため今回のように`git revert`とコマンドを打った場合には、通常受け付けられないコマンドですよというメッセージになります。

英文を確認していただければわかると思いますが、
usageが使い方で

```
git revert [<option>] <commit-ish>...
```

と使いましょうという意味です
`[]`は任意の入力項目で
`<>`は自分で設定する入力値です

revertコマンドの場合は特定のコミットの内容を打ち消すことになるので
と呼ばれるコミットのようなもの（コミットのハッシュ値でOK）が必要です
は`--quit`や`--continue`のことであり
もし利用する場合は

```
git revert --quit --continue <コミットのハッシュ値>
```

以下のURLが参考になると思います
gitの公式ドキュメント git revert
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert

サルでもわかるGit入門 revert
http://www.backlog.jp/git-guide/stepup/stepup7_2.html

Comment: 本当に助かります。今手探りの状況ですので。。